# Inject object with "request" scope into prototype object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, spring.net

I use Spring.Net in my Asp.Net MVC application where controllers must be defined as prototypes (non singleton). I have objects that must have a request scope (new object for each request). Is there a way to inject them into my controller?

```
  <object type="xx.CompanyController, xx" singleton="false">
    <property name="Service" ref="ServiceA" />
  </object>

  <object id="ServiceA" type="xx.ServiceA, xx" scope="request"/>    
    <property name="ObjectB" ref="ObjectB" />
  </object>

  <object id="ObjectB" type="xx.ObjectB, xx" scope="request"/>
```

Like this all objects except the controllers are treated as singleton.
ObjectB must not be prototype beause it is referenced by some other objects that need to share the same instance. Removing singleton="false" from the controller and add scope="request" also doesn't work (controller is treated as singleton).

I use Spring.Net 1.3.1 with MvcApplicationContext

Comment: I've noticed the same behavior.  Namely, objects defined with **request** scope get "promoted" to singleton scope if they are a dependency of a **singleton** object.

Answer (score 0):

You should set ControllerFactory with your own.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
//...
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new IoCControllerFactory());
//...
}
```

IoCControllerFactory must inherit from DefaultControllerFactory

```
public class IoCControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
```

And override GetControllerInstance

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance (RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        ObjectTypeUtility.ArgumentIsNull(controllerType, "controllerType", true);
         if (!typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType))
             throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                       "Type requested is not a controller: {0}",
                       controllerType.Name), 
                        "controllerType");    

            IController controller = IoCWorker.Resolve(controllerType) 
                                      as IController;                
            return controller;

    }
```

IoCWorker is a class has Resolve method for injection, *I am using Unity and I could not give IoCWorker implementation -if you need i can share-.*

It will work ctor inject for your controller.

Good luck.

Comment: The question is not if IoC in asp.net MVC is possible (I already use it with Spring.Net) but about the different (Spring-)scopes of (Spring-)object definitions.